# Can Sequelize.js for Node.js define a table where the Primary Key is not named 'id'?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a simple MySQL table named `things`. My `things` table has three columns:

```
Column Name  Data Type
===========  ============
thing_id     INT           // The auto increment Primary Key
thing_name   VARCHAR(255)
thing_size   INT
```

As far as I can tell Sequelize.js expects/requires the Primary Key be named 'id'.

Is there a way to use the standard `sequelize.define()` call to define the my `things` table? If not, is there another way?

Comment: Sequelize earlier only supported "id" as PK but in later versions should fully support custom primary keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
var Test = sequelize.define( 'things', {
    thing_id   : {type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11), primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    thing_name          : {type: Sequelize.STRING(255)},
    thing_size      : {type: Sequelize.INTEGER}
},{
});

Test.sync()
.success(function(){
    console.log('table created');
})
.error(function(error){
    console.log('failed', error)
})
```